# New Small Business, New IT Engineer, Need help on design and hardware

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, ethernet, internet

I've recently helped my friend start his business and now he wants me to take control of the IT side of things, I graduated university recently so my experience isn't so great, I was wondering if you could take a look at my somewhat "diagram" and give me comments and question just to make sure I have thought of everything . . . as in after I've configured the router and switch to serve their basic functions.

*** UPDATED DIAGRAM ***

[image]

Comment: The 172.16.0.0/24 range is not big enough to include any of the other ranges that you have for the departments.  You would need, at least 172.16.0.0/21. Are you doing NAT? The Cisco switch can't NAT.

Comment: Are you sure? It is a layer 3 switch, I thought it would have NAT, The network does require it to connect to the outside world.

Comment: The ONLY Cisco switch that does NAT is the 6509. Cisco claims it needs hardware to do NAT that is not included on any of their other switch models.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your IP address range (172.16.0.0/24) is not big enough to include all the address ranges which you wish to use.  You will need, at least, 172.16.0.0/21 to encompass the listed ranges.

Your Cisco switch, layer-3 or not, doesn't do NAT which you seem to require.

If you are at all concerned about security, you need to include a firewall between you and the ISP.  Also, for layer-2 security, I would recommend you not use VLAN 1 (shut it down and manually prune it), or any native VLAN.  Start your VLAN numbers higher than 1, remove VLAN 1 from the allowed trunk VLANs, and do not define any other untagged VLAN.

Comment: The design should include a good enough router (doesn't have to be a Cisco device) placed between the ISP ntu and the 2960XR switch which appears to have some L3 routing with the "IP-Lite High-Performance Routing" .  Specs on one of many Juniper firewalls that has an inbuilt SFP http://www.juniper.net/us/en/products-services/security/srx-series/srx110/#/

Answer (score 1):

Well, 172.160.0.0/26 isn't going to work - that's only 62 usable IPs. So what you're looking to do is create 5 VLANs? If you have a L3 switch, this will work fine and you can make each VLAN a /24. Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, I am. Hopefully the new diagram explains a bit more

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you're looking for, but I have comments on the diagram itself.

- The "End Users" (no apostrophe) might be better represented as five clouds, one for each VLAN & subnet.
- Since it's a diagram of network objects, it would be better to call the nodes at the bottom "Workstations" or "Computers" or "End User Nodes" since typically the word "User" refers to a person or a set of credentials, neither of which would be connected to a network.
- I would omit the patch panel entirely, unless you really want to reflect the premise wiring in which case I would add in a cloud (or something) of faceplates or drops between the patch panel and the workstations.
- The most confusing thing to me is the arrow to the "Fiber Connected by SFP Module" box. It looks like network traffic is being split off and sent one-way out to some other device. If that's meant to be a callout with details of the connection betweent the switch and the router, the arrow head should be pointing at the connection and not touching it. Another way to do that would be to change the line style or color for that connection and have a key in a corner indicating that the line style or color means fiber.
- You'll thank yourself later if you put as much detail as possible in there. What is the model number of the switch? The make and model of the router? The actual ISP? Maybe you removed those before posting for security. If not, adding them will make the diagram a lot more useful.

Not related to the diagram itself:

I find the IP information confusing, like greyaxe90. A 26-bit subnet mask is two bits longer than 255.255.255.0. Did you mean 172.16.0.0/**16** and then each of the other ranges would be 172.16.x.0/24? (A network address would not end with a 1 for the last octet with those subnet masks, BTW)

There are a lot of unanswered questions in what you have there. How is routing being done? What IP addresses are assigned to the router interfaces? What address(es) (if any) will be assigned to the switch?

One more thought: Even though he's a friend, you should still do all the paperwork for your business relationship with him. Definitely make monthly invoices for your work, unless he will be issuing a 1099 (or W-2) for you at the end of year. If you're not a full employee (W-2), keep track of all the time you work and what you do, even the work you don't charge for (if any). You might want to write a contract just in case. Totally outside of the realm of this StackExchange but having been down that road I couldn't not write something about it.